# Unitary operator and orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm reading a proof in which use the next affirmation:

Let $U:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ be an unitary operator, where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space. Let $E$ be a linear subspace of $\mathcal{H}.$ Then $U(E^{\bot})=(U(E))^{\bot}.$

I'm trying to prove it, but I'm stuck. I can't see how to use the fact of $U$ is unitary.

Any kind of help is thanked in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left<Ux,Uy\right>=\left<x,U^{\ast}Uy\right>=\left<x,y\right>=0$ for $x\in E^{\perp}$ and $y\in E$. This reasoning proves $U(E^{\perp})\subseteq(U(E))^{\perp}$.

For $z\in(U(E))^{\perp}$, let $x=U^{\ast}z$, by similar reasoning one shows that $x\in E^{\perp}$.

Comment: Wow! Many Thanks @user2843431. So pretty!

Comment: Actually this proves only one direction, can you figure out the other one? The other one actually is similar to the above reasoning.

Comment: I think I can handle with other direction. Thanks again @user284331.